# ng-form to submit dynamically created form without specific ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, input

**Edited the code to ask the question better**
*And thanks for all the help from everyone so far!*
I have some dynamically created input boxes that do not have a fix number of inputs and would like to submit them as you go....
how could I pass inputs from the input text boxes from the dynamically created form?
Hopefully my question make sense?
the form I am trying to submit is as follow:
how do I pass values into the create()? passing a currently does not work... and referencing $scope.a gets 'undefined'... :(
Please help thank you!

```
<form ng-submit="create(a)">
    <div class="module-head text-center">
        <b class="lead">{{ module.heading }}</b>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" id="submit" value="+"/>
    </div>
    <div class="module-body">
        <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="field in module.fields">
            <label class="control-label">{{field.name}}</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="fields"
                 ng-model="a[$index]" ng-init="a[$index]=field.data">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you creating new inputs?

Comment: @edward Knowles! first of all thanks! So, I'm pulling inputs out of the backend database that is a reference to two different tables but had to try to make it really dynamic as user can create more input fields... if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<form ng-submit="create()">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" id="submit" value="+"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" name="fields" ng-model="itemArray[$index]">
    </div>
</form>
```

When you submit this, the itemArray will have all the model values of the input fields.

To assign the original values to the input boxes.

```
<input type="text" name="fields" ng-model="a[$index]" ng-init="a[$index]=item"/>
```

Comment: Hi Paja007! thanks! But I'm still confused cause the "item in items" actually has previous value I pull out from the items array and this way I can't seem to pull out the original value?

Comment: Edited. Hope this is what you intended. If not please clarify. What exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi paje007! This did work for me! :) but I just realized I have another set of issues after this... my ng-repeat is actually nested within another ng-repeat so the $index value doesnt get retained i dont think... what do you think? any suggestions? its kinda hard to explain without a fiddle i suppose but its kinda hard to type up a fiddle as well since its complicated... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question, but if your concern is to access the `ng-model` values in controller you can create an `array` line `$scope.arr=[];`

And in your form use it like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" name="fields" ng-model="arr[item]"/>
</div>
```

In this way `$scope.arr` will have all your input values.

See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13274/

Comment: Hi Sourabh! thanks! I think this is going on the right direction since $scope.arr should retain all the information but how about the original values inside the item in items? it doesn't seem to be binding with the input field?

Comment: @brybry. Its kind of difficult to solve without looking into the issue. Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/) if possible to replicate the issue?

Comment: ! I agree it is a very hard to solve without playing/seeing the working issue actually unworking issue :( ... let me try to create a fiddle! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would try doing as:

```
<form ng-submit="create()">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" id="submit" value="+"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" name="fields" ng-model="items[$index]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Manasi Sakhare! thanks! this doesn't seem to bind the original data inside of the items to display the original values... for some reason... :(

Comment: Hey I just tried doing that in the fiddle. It does work

Comment: Have a look at my code here in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/AouerMrFpyDFK1RW6vOi?p=preview

Comment: Hi Manasi! thanks! Oh I made a newbie mistake thats why it didnt work when i fiddled... but now i have another set of issues that relates to this as i explained with paje007's response!